# Selecting coefficents to plot as dot-and-whiskers

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, gam, broom

I would like to plot the results of a GAM as dot-and-whisker plots using the dwplot() command in the dotwhisker R package. The example in the package documentation is as follows:

```
#Package preload
library(dotwhisker)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
# run a regression compatible with tidy
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + disp + gear, data = mtcars)
m1_df <- tidy(m1) # create data.frame of regression results
m1_df # a tidy data.frame available for dwplot
dwplot(m1_df) #same as dwplot(m1)
```

I have two questions:

1. I only want to plot two of the coefficients. How could I change the command to plot only, say, wt and cyl and exclude disp and gear.
2. How can I make the whiskers go vertically instead of horizontally (like in a "small multiple" plot, small_multiple())

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
dwplot(m1_df) + ylim(breaks=c("wt","cyl")) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

In the `ylim()` function, you can specify the breaks (factors) to include when the axis is discrete. And `coord_flip()` simply flips the plot around.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how we can rename the variables in the plot?

Answer (score 0):

The above is correct. In order to relabel, You have to relabel all of the predictors before using the `ylim()` function.

```
dwplot(list(m1_df)) %>%
  relabel_predictors(
        c(
           wt = "weight"
           cyl = "cylinder"  
           disp = "display"
           gear = "gear" )) + ylim(breaks=c("weight","cylinder")) + coord_flip()
```

And if you use an interaction term in your model, you'd have to rename the interaction using quotations, such as "wt:cyl" = "weight x cylinder"